# Detect correct iPad orinatation

Tags: ios, swift

I have to detect the orientation of the device and so something configuration based on it.
I write a simple function to handle it

```
public func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

It works perfectly on iPhone, but on iPad it's not. Sometimes when iPad is on landscape, it shows that it's `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` is larger than `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`, which is super weird.

So for iPad, I change to it like that

```
public func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    if DeviceType.isPhone {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    } else {
        return UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight || UIDevice.current.orientation == .unknown
    }
}
```

But still not working probably on iPad. The case of `unknown` is called sometimes on portrait and sometimes on landscape.
Is there any other way, that could works flawlessly? I really need to have a prefect way to always show the the iPad and iPhone that they are in portrait and landscape? Those `unknown`, `faceDown` and `faceUp` are really confusing and make problems in our workflow.

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape)
{
     print("[UI] Landscape")
}
else
{
     print("[UI] Portriat")
}
```

You will receive a warning saying that `.statusBarOrientataion` is deprecated, but I tested with Xcode 14 on an iPad Air 4th generation (iPadOS 15.7), and iPhone 12 (iOS 16), and it worked.